# Advanced Search in only URLs matching a certain string

Tags: google-search, bing

I want to search in all GitHub sub-pages containing the word "ja.po", like this page:

https://github.com/xfce-mirror/thunar/blob/master/po/ja.po?fbclid=IwAR0tWpLbL92YycE7yVZS6_u0lQwqLuyosIWxSXP1T_wOhVY_p31iJ-5uvzc

Inside each of the matching URL, I want to search for specific keywords

Is there a way to do that in Google, or any other search engine?

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly* what you want (since I expected the URL you mentioned to be shown as well) but you can combine the `site:` and `filetype:` directives and search e.g. for

```
site:github.com filetype:po "ja.po" "Sort items in descending order"
```

([Google results for the above query](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+filetype%3Apo+%22ja.po%22+%22Sort+items+in+descending+order%22))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- copy/paste this into either Bing or Google:

  ```
  allinurl:"ja.po" site:github.com
  ```
- or less strict:

  ```
  site:github.com "ja.po"
  ```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]